# The correct styling is applied despite the targeting are different in JSX and CSS files

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, jsx

Currently I have the following code:
`FormInput.jsx`:

```
import './FormInput.scss';

const FormInput = ({ label, ...otherProps} ) => {
    const { value } = otherProps;
    return (
        <div className="group">
            <input className="formInput" {...otherProps} />
            {label && (
                <label 
                    className={`${value.length ? 'shrink' : ''} formInput-label`}
                >{label}</label>
            )}
        </div>
    )
};

export default FormInput;
```

In `FormInput.scss`:

```
.formInput-label {
    transition: 300ms ease all;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 18px;
    left: 5px;
    top: 10px;

    &.shrink {
        top: -14px;
    }
}
```

What I'm confused about is that the targeted class of the `label` in `FormInput.jsx` should compile to:

```
.shrink .formInput-label
```

But the one in the SASS file will compile to:

```
.formInput-label.shrink
```

My question is how does the correct styling still get applied if the class targeting in the JSX and SASS files aren't the same? The JSX has the classes in reverse order and a space in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class attribute (or `className` in JSX) defines a list of classes. The syntax for classes is different in HTML and in CSS, but the order of classes on the same element does not matter in either.

JSX renders to HTML, so it renders as `class="shrink formInput-label"`, which defines the list of classes `["shrink", "formInput-label"]` and is compatible with the CSS selector `.shrink.formInput-label`.

Also, a CSS selector such as `.shrink` would match the element as well (just with a lower specifity rating), because it matches one of the classes in the list.

Comment: 1) If I understand your answer correctly, are you saying that it will also match `.shrink .formInput-label`? 2) And I'm still confused because the order on the CSS file is the other way around `.formInput-label.shrink` so I'm not sure why that still matches

Comment: `.shrink .formInput-label` wouldn't necessarilly match because in CSS the space has an entirely different meaning: It means "an element with the class `formInput-label` which is a descendant of another element with the class `.shrink`. The order of classes on the same element does not matter though, each class is matched separately. It asks "Does the element have the class `formInput-label` in it's list of classes - yes or no?

Comment: ah okay, I'm getting it now! So on the JSX, if I want to denote a parent child relationship, how should I write it? For example, I want to indicate that the `shrink` class to be a child of `formInput-label`

Comment: Parent-child relationship refers to *elements*, not to *classes*, the classes are only used to target the elements. If you have a structure of nested elements like `<div className="formInput-label"><div className="shrink"></div></div>` then the selector `.formInput-label .shrink` would match the inner one.